# сервер sftp windows

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

Подскажите как создать сервер sftp ?

Задача стоит протестировать некую библиотеку, в которой query запрос и другие параметры (generic) и отправить файл csv с использованием ssh key и библиотеки

я создала консольное приложение, добавила библиотеки, посмотрела  как использовать [ssh.net](https://codeburst.io/working-with-sftp-in-net-core-f1f464ab06f8) и есть уже сгенерированные ключи ssh.

Вопрос : чтобы протестировать данное задание, и возможно ли создать на своем компьютере, если кто может открыть завесу и просветлить

Необходимо отправить файл и узнать как работает программа, над которой я работаю, не могу найти документацию или легкое объяснение на русском языке, понимаю, что SFTP (“SSH File Transfer Protocol” или “Secure File Transfer Protocol”) но не понимаю как сложить пазл, и чтобы быть более точной в своем вопросе

```
new SftpConfig()
{
    Host = "?",
    Port = ?,
    UserLogin = "?"
};
```

то, что порт это порт, который слушает сервер это понятно, и пример порт 22, тоже попадалось на глаза, но как заполнить данные, чтобы на своем компьютере протестировать и что вписать в парамметры, чтобы было валидно и доступно локально

Comment: Вы сами справились с Вашей проблемой, это очень круто, но было бы еще круче, чтобы Вы оформили решение в виде ответа, ответить на свой же вопрос -- абсолютно нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Оформила решение в виде ответа...***

Мне удалось создать на одном посте сервер и со своего установив клиент ssh попробовать подключиться

я оставлю тут полезные ссылки :

[Настройка OpenSSH-сервера на Windows Server 2019](https://serverspace.ru/support/help/nastrojka-openssh-servera-na-windows-server-2019/)

[файл sshsshd_config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#HostKey)

[Установка и настройка SFTP сервера (SSH FTP) в Windows на базе OpenSSH](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2016/03/31/sftp-ssh-ftp-na-windows-server-2012-r2/)

Мне удается подключиться через powerShell с использованием ключей rsa, Я запустила тестовое приложение с использованием ssh.net
вот код

```
var config = new SftpConfig
{
    Host = "IPserver", // 
    Port = 22,
    UserLogin = "LoginName"
};
// step1 create an instance of SftpClient
using var client = new SftpClient(config.Host, config.Port, config.UserLogin);

var pk = new PrivateKeyFile("rsa_key/rsa_test");
var keyFiles = new[] { pk };

var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(config.UserLogin, keyFiles));

var con = new ConnectionInfo(config.Host, config.Port, config.UserLogin, methods.ToArray());

try
{
    // step 2.
    client.Connect();
    using var stream = File.OpenRead("...");
    client.UploadFile(stream, "...", true);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    /* client.Disconnect();

        throw new Exception($"{exception.Message} {exception.InnerException}");*/

    Debug.WriteLine("===================>" + $"{exception.Message} {exception.InnerException} {exception.Data} {exception.InnerException}");
}
finally
{
    // step 3.
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

после строчки **client.Connect();** он сразу бросает исключение ***Message = "Permission denied (publickey)."***

я создаю переменную **con**, чтобы добавить ключи rsa, но не использую ее, подскажите, как изменить код, чтоб работал, ведь с помощью ключей подключиться через powershell получилось

```
var pk = new PrivateKeyFile("rsa_key/id_rsa_test");  
var keyFiles = new[] { pk };

var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(config.UserLogin, keyFiles));

var con = new ConnectionInfo(config.Host, config.Port, config.UserLogin, methods.ToArray());
using var client = new SftpClient(con);
```

Получилось подключиться...
Теперь бы файл загрузить

```cs
var config = new SftpConfig
{
    Host = "IPserver", 
    Port = 22,
    UserLogin = "LoginName"
    PrivateKeyFilePath = "keyRSA_private"
    PrivateKeyFilePassphrase = "pathPhrase"
};

// step1 create an instance of SftpClient with RSA key
var keyFiles = 
    new[]{ new PrivateKeyFile(config.PrivateKeyFilePath, config.PrivateKeyFilePassphrase) };

var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(config.UserLogin, keyFiles));

var con = new ConnectionInfo(config.Host, config.Port, config.UserLogin, methods.ToArray());
using var client = new SftpClient(con);

try
{
    // step 2.
    client.Connect();
    
    // step bonus => send file
    var localFilePath = "test.txt"
    var remoteFilePath = "testFileForSendingToServer.txt" 
    
    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
          client.UploadFile(fileStream, remoteFilePath, true); // true for readonly
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    logger.LogInformation(exception, 
        $"Failed in uploading file [{localFilePath}] to [{remoteFilePath}]");
}
finally
{
    // step 3.
    client.Disconnect();
}
```