# Отправить файл через SFTP с помощью SSH.NET

Tags: c#, консоль, ssh, sftp

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162046/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-sftp-windows) я пыталась подключиться, подключение работает.

Теперь не получается отправить файл, может кто-то знает ответ, может кто-то уже сталкивался?

Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
client.Connect();

var stringforUpload = "/C:/folder/file.csv";
var stringForDownload = @"C:\folder\file.csv";
var localFile = "file.csv"; // в самом проектеь в корне

// тут программа работает и все без ошибок, но файл не вижу на втором компе 
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile))
    client.UploadFile(fileStream, stringforUpload , true);

// поэтому решила может надо не Upload а Download, но тут выдает ошибку
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(stringForDownload))
    client.DownloadFile(localFile, fileStream);
```

Comment: [Вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226403/12888024). Мне кажется, слеш в начале `stringforUpload` лишний.

Comment: Во-первых предыдущий комментатор прав, а во-вторых, вторым параметром UploadFile должен быть не путь, а просто имя файла: file.csv. Посмотрите хороший пример загрузки файла по этой ссылке: https://gist.github.com/DavidDeSloovere/96f3a827b54f20d52bcfda4fe7a16a0b

Comment: столько писала и не сохранилось...ща

Comment: Вопрос был Download или Upload, вот в чем вопрос и есть ли разница в использовании. Путь с со слешом вначале корректный хоть и странный, но почему то с первого раза не сработало, и я сразу перешла на альтернативный поиск => download, там антислеши в стринге, но я так и не докопала, вернулась к upload, и добавила иф файл нуль....хм, незнаю видимо для первого раза необходима проверка, хотя я не уверенна, но сработало и да верно, там не важен путь, а только название файла, а путь уже есть в нашем клиенте с его конфигурациями, но добавив, это как повторение ни коем образом не ломающее стринг.

Comment: примеры просмотрела, программист там тестирует на буфферСайз если файл большой, то выдаст ошибку, что в моем случае не было необходимо, хотя я себе оставила на заметку, а в целом логика таже. Благодарю за ваши комментарии

Comment: @Dev18, естественно для загрузки файла на удаленный комп надо использовать Upload, он не работал, видимо, именно из-за неверного параметра. Download падал с ошибкой потому что указанного файла не существует на удаленной машине.

Comment: не ну правда, я не меняла стринг для upload , это потом я рефакторила в коде, потому что это повторение пути, который уже есть в клиете✔, но сработало после проверки иф файл нюль, и после он создал‍♀️ file на сервере, а на счет dowload, я не стала дальше искать ответов, код для него не рабочий, и хотелось бы узнать разницу и еще если кто знает побольше исключений, чтобы сообщения были более точными в консоли

Comment: ‍♀️слеш вначале пути...что он делает, он выходит и потом опять заходит в диск C по указанному пути... и тут мы возвращаемся к Вашему комментарию, что должен быть не путь, а просто имя файла...а без слеша вначале пути именно что давал ошибку